# Не работает заголовок header refresh в Chrome

Tags: браузер, header, php, google-chrome

```
header('refresh:1 url=index.php');
exit('Доступ запрещен!');
```

В FF нормально, в хроме не работает. refresh не на себя.

Comment: @Zepp, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Да, поэтому! Спасибо!)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть потому, что пропущена точка с запятой после задержки обновления ?

```
refresh:1; url=index.php
```